# How to edit linked app.config and save changes in all exe config

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

I am working on winform c# application, having single app.config linked in all the projects.
I'm trying to create one project, which can edit and update connection string in app.config. But currently I'm only able to change particular project's exe.config. 
How I can change all exe.config in particular solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through all exe.config file in application folder and using XmlDocument; I'm changing connection string for all and saving it again.

```
  string curAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string FolderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(curAssembly);
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FolderPath).Where(x => x.EndsWith(".config")).ToArray();
            foreach (string item in files)
            {
                XmlDocument XmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                XmlDoc.Load(item);
                foreach (XmlElement xElement in XmlDoc.DocumentElement)
                {
                    if (xElement.Name == "connectionStrings")
                    {
                        foreach (XmlElement xChild in xElement)
                        {
                            if (xChild.Attributes.Count > 1 && xChild.Attributes[0].Value == ConfigSectionName)
                            {
                                xChild.Attributes[1].Value = "Data Source=" + cmbDatasource.Text + ";Initial Catalog=" + cmbDatabaseName.Text + ";UID=" + txtUserName.Text + ";password=" + txtPassword.Text + ";Integrated Security = false;";
                                Connectionstring = xChild.Attributes[1].Value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                XmlDoc.Save(item);
            }
```